# Удалить строку с определенным символом в HTML через JS

Tags: javascript, html

Т.к я не очень силен в JS прошу помощи.
Нужно удалить строку из *textarea* с определенным символом.
Пример: удалить строку с символом ":" из:

```
test
test:123
```

Должно получится:

```
test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function filter() {
  var substring = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
  var text = textarea.value;
  text = text.split('\n');
  text = text.filter(function(row) {
    return (row.indexOf(substring) == -1)
  })
  textarea.value = text.join('\n')
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" rows=5>test test:test test
</textarea>

<input id="input" value=":" />
<button onclick="filter()">filter</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<textarea id=txt>test test:123</textarea>

<script>
old = document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML;
// Регуляркой отрезаем всё, что после ":"
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = old.replace(/:.*/, '');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно взять содержимое textarea и сделать str.replace ненужной части (найти её можно регуляркой).

```
var textarea = document.getElementById( 'my-text-area-id' )
var str_to_change = textarea.innerHTML;
str_to_change = str_to_change.replace( /\w*:\w*/, '' ); // /\w*:\w*/g если нужна жадная регулярка.
textarea.innerHTML = str_to_change // устанавливаем новое значение в textarea
```

Если нужно произвольный символ заменять то

```
var rgxp = new RegExp( '\w*' + my_symbol + '\w*' );
str_to_change = str_to_change.replace( rgxp, '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('textarea').value.replace(/[^\n]*:[^\n]*\n?/g, ''))
```

```css
textarea { height: 5em; }
```

```html
<textarea>test
test:test
test
test:test</textarea>
```